# FogBugz api request for flat time estimates

Tags: api, http, fogbugz

I have a FogBugz application which gets data from their api and generates some reports. I need to get the hours estimate for each individual case I search for. From their API I can see that you get the hours, however those hours include all the ones of the child/dependent cases. I do not want those included in my results.

How can you request the time estimates for a specific case in fogBugz? As an analogy, If I do the current request with hrsEstimate I get a result which In FogBugz's WebApp equivalates to Grid View- Outline. I need to get the result that equivalates to Grid View - Flat.

Answer (score 0):

Does column `hrsCurrEst` work better?

http://help.fogcreek.com/the-fogbugz-api/cases#Column_Titles

Comment: Not really. All the columns ignore the request to get a the sum of total hours of the current case and all child cases. From what I can gather it's a limitation of the XML Api. It does not give an error but does not tell you that you can't do that.